# Error in EL Expression

Tags: jstl, el

I am trying to use `fn:length` and `c:when` together

```
<c:when test="${fn:trim(${properties.num2display})== null}">
    <c:set var="counter" value="3"/>
    condition 1 
</c:when>
```

Gives me the Error :

```
contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:
    ${fn:trim(${properties.num2display})== null}
```

What is the correct way to write the expression inside `fn:trim`?

Comment: I guess you should use `${empty fn:trim(${properties.num2display})}` (not tested though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<c:when test="${not empty fn:trim(properties.num2display)}">
    <c:set var="counter" value="3"/>
    condition 1 
</c:when>
```